# NGXS: Testing an action

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm very new to angular & ngxs and I'm coding a small message-service giving the opportunity to send & receive Messages through an ngxs store connected to firebase.

I'm trying to write a test for the method to send messages. As I'm not really getting along with the official ngxs documentation for testing, I'm having some issues with that.

So my current (not working) attempt for that test is:

```
describe('SendMessage', () => {
    let store: Store;
    let testData: Message = {
    author: 'testauthor',
    text: 'testtext'
}; 

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([MessageState]),
            NgxsModule.forRoot([AngularFirestore])],
        }).compileComponents();

        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        store.reset(TEST_STATE);
     }));

    it('sends Messages', async(() => {
        store.dispatch(new fromMessage.AddMessage(testData));
        store.selectOnce(state => MessageState.getSentMessages).subscribe(message => {
           expect(message).toEqual(testData);
    })
   }))   
});
```

With TEST_STATE being

```
export const TEST_STATE = {
    messages: [{
    author: 'testauthor',
    text: 'testtext'
    }]
}
```

Running the test, I get the error `Failed: States must be decorated with @State() decorator`.

How can I use the TEST_STATE correctly as my state for testing `AddMessage`? How should my dispatches and selects look like?

As I said, I am a newbie to ngxs and testing, so sorry if my Code is not so good.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look https://ngxs.io in the concepts section.  You need a state container class, the class has to have actions, you dispatch and action and it fires the associated action(s) in the state container(s), which may (or may not) update the state.  I'd try get a simple one component angular app working with NGSX before trying to wire up a test case.

Comment: Well, I already got that sate Container class, with working state model and working actions dispatching to the store. Everything works fine but now I got to write that unit test and this is where the documentation does not help me anymore. In the example above I tried to mock a state (TEST_STATE) containing the desired objects as recommended by the ngxs testing-documentation but I dont understand how to get further...

Comment: I don't think you want to create a mock state at all - you really want to test the *real* state, by dispatching actions that modify the state and then verifying that the state has been updated as you expected.

Comment: @GarthMason Doing that means testing the framework itself. You should only need to test that you are dispatching the correct actions when you click, and separately, without dispatching, that your state is updated correctly when passed this action and some part of the state as parameters. This is what NgRx allows. Is it even possible with NGXS? According to the docs, no. You need to dispatch and subscribe every time, and use the complete real store or a global mock.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much you want to mock - with NGXS we've mocked minimal stuff so far, just http service dependencies.  If I wanted to check only that a certain action is dispatched, I'd listen to the NGXS action stream `ofActionDispatched` for that action type, and assert that is called.

Answer (score 3):

There are two lines in your testbed's imports statement that might produce the error `Failed: States must be decorated with @State() decorator`:

1. NgxsModule.forRoot([MessageState]) and
2. NgxsModule.forRoot([AngularFirestore])

Please double check if the classes `MessageState` and  `AngularFirestore` are decorated with `@State()`.